# Change decompiler in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I'm switching decopilers in Visual Studio (from dotPeek to .NET Reflector) but are unable to find the setting in Visual Studio.

Can anyone advice me?

Thanks

Comment: Visual Studio doesn't use decompilers.

Comment: No, thats why I have plugins like the ones I mention.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that Resharper had stolen the decompilation management. Changing this setting to "Default Visual Studio navigation" in the menu Resharper / Options / Tools / External Sources solved the issue